# Bugg with NSDictonary sometimes crashes with "Trying to insert nil" response

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, nsdictionary

I´m having a great deal of trouble with a bugg that in some cases gives the "initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[6]'" error message. It´s only occurring around every third trial and in the other cases it works fine. I haven´t debugged buggs that happeds at certain situations so that´s whyI´m asking for help. It might be difficult to find a solution but I would be glad to receive some advice atleast where to start look for the issue and how to debug it?

Basically my app have a method that sends a NSDictonary list with objects to a server. In some cases I want to remove an object if the user have´t chosen anything for that list. Problem is that the server died´t like sending an object with an empty space. So I made a kind of not nice looking work around. Basically The IBaction checks if the Object contains nil. If it contains nil it redirects to a very similar NSDictonary without the Object containing Nil. It woks in some cases but it seems like it sometimes don´t recognize the object containing nil.

Here´s the code in Inaction that redirects the code. I haven´t created a method for inserting anything to the object:@"DefaultCreateImageID" yet so as far as I know it should always be nil.

```
 NSString *Imagestuff= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DefaultcreateImageID"];
    if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DefaultcreateImageID"] !=  ( NSString *) [NSNull null]  ){
    DataHandler *handler = [DataHandler sharedDatahandler];
    handler.authenticateUserDelegate = self;
    [handler createActivityNoImage];
        NSLog(Imagestuff);
    }

    else
    {
        DataHandler *handler = [DataHandler sharedDatahandler];
        handler.authenticateUserDelegate = self;
        [handler createActivity];

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error "Trying to insert nil" then one of the objects you are trying to add to the dictionary is nil. Solution: Don't do that.

Figure out why some item you are trying to add to the dictionary is nil. Then figure out what you want to do in the situation.

Comment: Well I could easily replace the nil with something else but that would´t solve the real problem. My method needs to know if the user has added anyhitng to that object. If they haven't I need to not send that object to the server. Problem is that when I ask what the string is containing nil it sometimes  seems to miss it and stil sends it to the NSDictonary. The error is created when the object containing nil is sent. If I would replace it with something else then like a blanc space the server instead would still give an error.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on gnashers729 answer. The problem for me isn't nil but the fact my Inaction fails to reqognize what the object contains.

Here for example I tried to replace nil with a string to reqognize. I get the same problem that my method in some cases recognize the string and in some cases don´t.

```
NSString *Imagestuff= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DefaultcreateImageID"];
    if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DefaultcreateImageID"] !=  ( NSString *) @"noImage"  ){
```